# how to make a module install in linux

Tags: linux, software-installation, kernel-modules

im new to linux , and im using linux clear distribution

im trying to conect my DSLR to be like webcam 
trying make this module to install and it not working

this is my output

```
$ make
Building v4l2-loopback driver...
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=/home/yukehi/הורדות/v4l2loopback-master modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.3.11-868.native/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:43: v4l2loopback.ko] Error 2
```

and this is the makefile 
i dont understand what i need to change here

`v4l2loopback-master`

```
KERNELRELEASE   ?= `uname -r`
KERNEL_DIR  ?= /lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)/build
PWD     := $(shell pwd)
obj-m       := v4l2loopback.o

PREFIX ?= /usr/local
BINDIR  = $(PREFIX)/bin
MANDIR  = $(PREFIX)/share/man
MAN1DIR = $(MANDIR)/man1
INSTALL = install
INSTALL_PROGRAM = $(INSTALL) -p -m 755
INSTALL_DIR     = $(INSTALL) -p -m 755 -d
INSTALL_DATA    = $(INSTALL) -m 644

MODULE_OPTIONS = devices=2
```

Comment: Write your complete question in the post, preferably explaining what you have tried. Also use the code formatting to make it clear what is script or terminal output and what is your own text.

Comment: Ok ^_^ tanks for the note . im new at linux

Comment: No worries. The clearer your question the better the answers will be. Read the posting notes and have a go at editing.

Comment: You should install the linux headers -- I'm not using clear linux, so I'm not able to help you further, but according to [this page](https://docs.01.org/clearlinux/latest/guides/kernel/kernel-modules.html), they should be in the `linux-dev` package.

Comment: Did you install the headers for your kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"make this module to install"*, and

*"how to make a module install"*

could combine into `make modules_install`, which is a special make target. These other two targets are included in `make` (if in the linux source dir):

```
* vmlinux         - Build the bare kernel
* modules         - Build all modules
```

That means `make modules` would **compile** all the configured modules.

But do you mean that kind of "making a module"?

Maybe it is enough to `modprobe v4l2loopback`, after you have installed the package. That would be inserting, or adding, a module to the kernel, manually.